# cannot decode AMF encode messages from flash PHP

Tags: php, flash, amf, amfphp

I am receiving encoded data from flash in AMF format, but I want to decode it in php .

I do not know how can I use the library https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0/blob/master/Amfphp/Core/Amf/Serializer.php

I cant find a sample code that instructs how to do a simple decode of AMF encoded message

Comment: does it works with normal PHP?

Comment: I am  trying to find  a sample code or at least a pseudo code  of how it works

Comment: Is part of Zend Framework and you can use it since PHP 5.2, At this moment I don't know if you can use the component standalone or if you need download some dependency

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.amf.html

Comment: I need it to be standalone, unfortunately its not

Comment: Why do you want to decode an AMF message ? Couldn't you use remoting ? AMFPHP will encode/decode seamlessly. It is very rare to need direct encoding/decoding.

Comment: You can find your answer over [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12511536/1124037

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against using Zend_Amf, it was written with some mysterious misconception in mind, which they consider to be the "architecture"... AMFPHP still exists and is maintained by some folks who didn't like Zend that much http://sourceforge.net/projects/amfphp/

Here is their site with examples and explanation on how to set it up etc: http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once, and solved it as follows.

You can use javascript base64 encoding inside Flash while you can use base64_decode function in PHP. I have used before and it works perfectly.

Comment: wish I could use, but unfortunately client requirement is only AMF

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [nekoserver](http://code.google.com/p/nekoserver) project. It's simplified analogue of amfphp written in [Haxe](http://haxe.org). There you can find [nekoserver.amf.io](http://code.google.com/p/nekoserver/source/browse/trunk/nekoserver/amf/io/) package, look at `AmfDeserializer.hx` (reading metadata) and `Amf3Reader.hx` (reading message body). It's all very simple there. Well, I guess the fact that project is written in Haxe is not vey good for you, but you should not be affraid syntax of Haxe is very similar to Actionscript syntax.

Also I recomend to look at [AMF format specification](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/amf/amf3_spec_121207.pdf).

**PS.** Did I understood correctly that you need AMF3 (not AMF0)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a very reliable PHP extension for encoding/decoding AMF3 streams without the overhead of using pure PHP encoders/decoders - https://github.com/neoxic/php-amf3